# The Vendor Email associated with your app do not reflect the name,"xxxxxxxx"

Tags: ios

when I post my ios app to appstore. The checker of appstore of apple send message as below:

The Vendor Email associated with your app do not reflect the name,"xxxxxxxx".

SO what the "Vendor Email" means and how can I change it.

Answer (score 0):

Vendor email is developer details provide in the info tab .It's not matching vendor name . Please give a matching email related to app name